# Alternative for c# .Last

Tags: c#

Currently I am using .Last to find the last number in a database and then assign the incoming information a number that is plus one higher the last number.

```
var newId = (_logs.Last().RecordID + 1);
```

I was wondering if there's a different way of looking for the highest number and then adding one to that number for the new id.

Edit:

Saw a few responses and realised I didn't make it clear what database I'm using. I'm using an in-memory repository.

Comment: Some DBMS support [Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver15). Would that be an option? Or use AutoIncrement for an Identity Column.

Comment: Well, it is not as simple as it seems. You haven't specified which database you use, assuming it is an SQL database you could change the settings for ID column to 'identity column'. In this case it will automatically increment id in database

Comment: Use an Identity column. Your current way of creating the id is prone to [Race Condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Comment: Sort in the opposite order and use `.First()`?  Which I'd expect to be considerably more efficient for just about any RDBMS, since `.Last()` probably involves iterating an entire result set while `.First()` involves fetching only one record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use a identity Id column.
You can get the last id, by just request it from the database

```
var lastId = context.Table
     .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
     .Select(x => x.Id)
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

As Fabjian said in the comments, if you are using SQL Server, you should set the column as an *Identity Column* and then the ID will increment automatically. If you alter that, you new the ID of the inserted line you should terminate the query with: `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`; this will return you the ID of the line inserted.

If you only need to know the last ID of a table you can query with

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TABLE_NAME')
```

Comment: I attempted to edit this for clarity, but am still confused by what you're trying to say in (what's now) the second sentence. Can you [edit] your answer to clarify?